# awk pattern matching using variable with xml value

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, pattern-matching

so here's my awk script. It's in a file called mAwk.awk

```
#!usr/bin/awk -f
  BEGIN {
    FS="."
     artifactPattern="/<artifactId>artifactName1|artifactName2<\\/artifactId>/"
 #   print "-------------" artifactPattern
  }
  {
    toPrint = 1
    if ($0 ~ /<dependencies>/) {
      matches=1000;
    }
    else if ($0 ~ /<dependency>/) {
      matches +=100;
    }
    else if ($0 ~ /<\/dependency>/) {
      matches =1000;
    }
  else if ($0 ~ /<groupId>(com.group1.*)|(com.group2.*)|(com.group3.*)<\/groupId>/) {
      matches += 10;
    }
# else if($0 ~ /<artifactId>artifactName1|artifactName2<\/artifactId>/){
 else if($0~artifactPattern){
        matches += 1;
        }
  else if ($0 ~ /<version>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+<\/version>/) {
     print "debugging: matched 1 -", matches
      if (matches == 1111) {
        lastPart="0-SNAPSHOT</version>"
        print $1 "." $2+1 "." lastPart;
        matches -= 11;
        toPrint = 0
      }
    }
    else if ($0 ~ /<\/dependencies>/) {
      matches=0
    }
    if ( toPrint == 1) {
      print $0
    }
  }
  END {
  }
```

Now here's the structure of the xml file (it's a pom.xml), just in-case:

```
<project>
  <random tags/>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>data</groupId>
      <artifactId>data</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
      ... repeat...
  </dependencies>
</project
```

The problem is, if I use the line:

```
# else if($0 ~ /<artifactId>payment-common|test2-common<\/artifactId>/){
```

instead of the one just below it, it matches just fine, but when I put the value inside a variable, it fails. What's going on here?

My final aim is to call this through a shell script like...

```
awk -v pattern=`cat ./artifactPatterns.txt` mAwk.awk -f myFile.xml
```

and the artifactPatterns.txt will look like waht the variable holds in the awk file, example:

```
/<artifactId>artifactName1|artifactName2<\\/artifactId>/
```

I've tried a bunch of things and nothing seems to work, thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you considered using a tool like `xmlstarlet` to parse XML in shell scripts, instead of `awk`?

Comment: @Barmar Apparently not, although it has been suggested to him several times.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs Yeah, it seems like this guy is really determined to learn `awk` by asking questions every time he runs into a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the `//` delimiters around the value of `artifactPattern`. These are the syntax for regexp literals, they don't belong in strings. The use of the `~` operator implies that it's a regular expression.

And since `/` isn't a delimiter, you don't need to escape it inside the value.

```
artifactPattern="<artifactId>artifactName1|artifactName2</artifactId>"
```

Also, `$0 ~ /pattern/` can be simplified to just `/pattern/` -- when a regexp literal appears by itself, it defaults to matching against the whole line.